# Z-Ordering Markers in GoogleMap v2 Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

Before you downvote, let me say that I have searched at least 5 hours in different forums for solutions/hacks and those are the solutions I have tried so far:

- Calling `showInfoWindow()` to force the Marker to come to the front
- Order of addition of Markers to the Map
- Size of Drawables of Markers

I know there is no Z-Axis values in `MarkerOptions/Markers`.

**The Question**: Is there any hack/trick to order the Markers? (Even if we change Markers with clickable Overlays or so...)

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**
An example would be:

```
//Marker B
MarkerOptions mBOptions = objB.getMarkerOptions(); 
//mBOptions has Pos = (1/0) and Icon has a radius 1
Marker markerA = mGoogleMap.addMarker(mBOptions);

//Marker A
MarkerOptions mAOptions = objA.getMarkerOptions(); 
//mAOptions has Pos = (0/0) and Icon has a radius 10
Marker markerB = mGoogleMap.addMarker(mAOptions);
```

I want to force A to cover the Marker B no matter how I change the position of Marker A. I dont want Marker B to show on top of A.

Comment: what do you mean by "order the Markers" ? do you want to place them at different positions ?

Comment: My meaning of "z-ordering" is the way of how Markers are drawn on top of another? I know that Google renders the Markers from top to bottom. Example: A marker with a big icon (lets call it A) SHOULD (partially) cover another smaller marker (B), if the icon of A covers the location of B. My problem is that mostly B is drawn on top of A and I have absolutely no control over that.

Comment: can you post your code here ?

Comment: See the Edit 1 please.

Comment: I found out a trick that partially solves it. If two Markers are on th exat same position, if you reduce the latitude by 0.0001, then that marker will appear on top. This works online if the position of the Markers should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future references:

At the end I could NOT find a good solution to my problem besides the points mentioned in the question.